# Search for a substring in a string with a specific pattern with php

Tags: php

I've got a series of strings that are formated like A01B05. The parts with 01 and 05 can vary. A and B are static and do not change.
The String A01B05 can be a part of a bigger string. And I just need to know, if the string A01B05 is part of the parent string.

I tried

```
preg_match("/A**/B**","A04B05");
```

but this will not work at all.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Oh sorry, i missed a fact in my question. The String A01B05 can be a part of a bigger string. And I just need to know, if the string A01B05 is part of the parent string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One single character in regular expressions is `.` So I think you need this regexp:

```
preg_match('/A..B../', $str);
```

Comment: if you specifically want those characters to be numeric, try ``'/A\d\dB\d\d/'``.  see all the various escape chars at http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php